# Can I temporarily suspend auto-generated ID in ORMLite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, ormlite

I am using Android with ORMLite in a small app I am currently writing.  The app aims to have a working Import/Export function, for which I use Simple XML framework.  And everything works great, up to a point.

The situation is as follows: Object A contains a foreign key referencing Object B, which references Object C through a foreign key itself.  Exporting a database is great.  Importing works to, with a small caveat, namely that it works as long as the IDs of all object are sequential and start from 1.  But if the database is fragmented, i.e. I deleted a record here and there, after I export the database, I have "holes" in the generated XML structure. Example objects could be:

```
@DatabaseTable("orders")
public class Order {
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private int _id;
    @DatabaseField(columnName="date")
    private Date _date;
    @DatabaseField(columnName="cost")
    private double _cost;
    @DatabaseField(foreign = true, columnName="customer_id")
    private Customer _customer;
    // ... more fields, getters and setters
}

@DatabaseTable("customers")
public class Customer {
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true);
    private int _id;
    @DatabaseField
    private String _name;
    // ... more fields, getters and setters
}
```

Let's say I have a database with 2 customers (id 1 and 2), which hold respectively orders from 1 through 5 and 6 through 8.  Exporting this and then re-importing in a clean database works great. If however I delete customer 1 and their orders and export it, the exporter will write their id as they are, i.e.

```
<customer id="2">...</customer>
```

and

```
<order id="6">...</order>
<order id="7">...</order>
<order id="8">...</order>
<order id="9">...</order>
```

etc.  When I import the data into a fresh database, I would first save the customer object via

```
custDao.create((Customer)x);
```

and then each of their orders via

```
orderDao.create((Order)o);
```

The problem is that the create function disregards the provided id (which is not 0) and the newly generated id for customer is 1 (in a fresh, empty database). Same for the orders.  But since they reference customer with id=2, the link between them is broken.

So after this somewhat long-winded explanation, here is my question: Is there a way to tell ORMLite to take the provided value for a generatedId field and run with it, instead of overwriting it? I would be OK, if any Exception is generated in case the create function finds row already in the table with the same ID, but would proceed with saving the record otherwise...
I have thought of a work-around for this: all the objects should be sortable by ID using the Comparator interface; sort the ArrayList with objects to be imported; for each object - read supposed id into an int, - save to database using dao.create, - if the object's new id is different than supposed id, change it via dao.updateId, - move to the next object in the list...  But that seems too cumbersome and error-prone: What if the create method tries to generate an id, which you just re-assigned to a previous object with updateId?

I don't believe my situation is so rare, that no one has encountered this before.  I would appreciate a solution!

Best regards,
Todor

Comment: Just wanted to make sure you saw the update to my answer @todor.

Answer (score 2):

[ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) supports a `allowGeneratedIdInsert=true` option to `@DatabaseField` annotation that allows inserting of an object with the ID already set into a generated-id table.  If the value of the ID field is null or default value (0, ...) then the database will generate the ID.  This is not supported by all database types (Derby for example).  Here's [another discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073923/android-ormlite-insert-row-with-id) about this specific topic.

---

I do think the proper thing to do here is to build your object graph in memory, associating the *proper* `Customer` on their `Order` objects *before* saving an of them to disk.  If you read your Customers into memory, then read in the `Order` objects and set the real `Customer`object on each one.  When you then create each `Customer` object in the database, ORMLite will change the `id` field to the generated one which would change it on the `customer_id` field saved in each `Order` as well.

If you have a ton of data and can't read it all into memory at one (or for some other reason) then you could always build a `Map<Integer,Integer>` and save the `Customer` id from the XML mapped to the id you get after you create it in the database.  Then when you load in the `Order` objects you can set the new corrected id on the foreign object.

Hope this helps.  Let me know some more details about how you are reading in the objects and I can give a better example of how to build the object graph.

Comment: Well, yes, I agree that creating everything in memory and setting all the object relations before saving anything will work, however that is a solution for none but the most simplistic or small data sets. And it opens a whole 'nother can of worms: What if the data set is part of another desktop or server database - rewriting IDs will certainly break things. Or what if IDs are used for something else, like creating bills or delivery notices and someone needs to restore from backup? Changing IDs on database restore is a big no-no of every self-respecting database admin...

Comment: If you are talking about a database restore, I'll agree that changing ids is baaad.  I thought you were talking about a "small" Android application that is importing additional records from XML where there might be overlapping ids.  If there are overlapping ids that are referenced in other database, you've got other problems.  Does the 2nd part of my answer not help?  It shows you how to use a 2nd object to insert non generated ids into the same table.

Comment: Also, I very specifically point out in my answer that assembling the objects in memory is only for a small amount of data.  Did you actually read the entire answer?