# Retrieve data in the same order they were inserted : ormlite?

Tags: android, ormlite

I have to retrieve rows in same order they were inserted . I have realized that the order is changing by respecting the primary key. answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073923/android-ormlite-insert-row-with-id) query make sense to let the database generate the id and then have an additional field that you use that is set externally for your purposes. but the problem is I need to use `createorupdate` method according to the id that I have set as primary key now. Is there any other solutions to fetch the data in inserted order, something like by using `RowId` or anything other ?

Comment: For this kind of situation, you guys should always keep one habit that create your table with 2 compulsory columns as createdDate and lastUpdatedDate, So you can fetch data as per your requirement

Comment: But Say, If I have a feature for add products into my cart . and I'm adding one product with new date into my cart and a older date product then after . here in this scenario the product with new date will come to the front of the stack right when I need vice versa IE, latest added product at the top/bottom of the list ?

Comment: that you can manage by your select query as order by ascending or descending, default is ascending so you don't need to write anything, but if you want from bottom to top then just write as Order By CreatredDate DESC and you will get response as per your requirement

Comment: My scenario is entirely different and the solution given by you can't apply here. Say If I have products that got id's 1-10 by skipping 5. and the latest product from server which can be added to my product got the id 5. If I'm adding the product it will insert into the middle of the table there can't be used the date logic as we don't know when the products created .It can be shuffled.