# Ormlite unknown ROWID

Tags: android, ormlite

I have to find the physical location of a row by **ROWID** using `Ormlite`.

But when I tried to sort rows using  **ROWID** it throws the exception.

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown column name 'rowid' in table Deals
```

Code follows,

```
mDealsDao.queryBuilder().orderBy("rowid", true).query();
```

How can I overcome this worry ? Does any one have faced the Issue Prior... ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Unknown column name 'rowid' in table Deals

In the future, you should show the entity in question.  I suspect that your entity does not have `rowid` field.  Rather, I guess that `rowid` is an internal database feature.  If this is the case, you can deal with `rowid` in a raw sense but if you try to use it as a field, ORMLite is going to complain.

So you could use:

- [queryBuilder.orderByRaw("rowid")](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/QueryBuilder.html#orderByRaw(java.lang.String)) (`"rowid DESC"` for descending)
- [dao.queryRaw(...)](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao.html#queryRaw(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String...))

And other raw methods.

Comment: Yes I don't have `rowid` field in my entity . I have to use the internal feature `rowid` for fetching the row in the inserted order.

Comment: Don't you get things in `rowid` order by default?

Comment: Nope I have some primary key related worry that you have mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073923/android-ormlite-insert-row-with-id) . can u please lead me to get things using the [ROWID](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ROWID) feature in database ? Thanks for ur valuable time BTW.

Comment: In a nutshell, I have to get the the rows order by `rowid` ascending.

Comment: Great work. It does. now for my knowledge please let me know how can I sort those rows in descending order using `orderByRaw("rowid")`?