# How to insert a record with arbitrary id on a table with autoincrement using ORMLite on Android?

Tags: android, insert, ormlite

I need to pre-populate an SQLite database on my Android application.

My idea is to put an file into assets folder. Each line on this file contains a sql command like

```
INSERT INTO Books(id, name) VALUES(16, 'Book X');
```

The application will read line by line and will use raw query to insert the data into the database.

The problem is that id column has auto generated id. I think it will cause conflict with the use of an arbitrary id.

Someone knows how to use solve this problem?

Comment: Check out this answer and let me know if it helps.  If not, please provide more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216663/can-i-temporarily-suspend-auto-generated-id-in-ormlite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field with `@DatabaseField` annotation must have `allowGeneratedIdInsert=true`.

To avoid an exception, if the object with the id already exists, `createOrUpdate` method must be used instead create.

Edit: `createOrUpdate` is very time expensive. It's better use just create with great amounts of data.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
 @DatabaseField(columnName = sqlId, generatedId = true, allowGeneratedIdInsert = true)
```

and no other column can have id=true

Answer (score 0):

> You can use the following (generatedId = true) to generate autoincrement integer id with database.

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "todo")
public class Todo {

public Todo() {

    }

   @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private Integer id;


   public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```